# Kosher way to send data to REST service

Tags: web-services, rest

Suppose, I have a GET, PUT, POST and DELETE methods. I want to have them.
How should a data be sent to each of these methods?

1. I can send parameter in URL. Parse URL and get value from it.
2. A value can be sent inside body of request.
3. A value can be sent inside request's params (?).

What I want as an answer, are links to specifications of how request is made, what is sent, what is used for what. Also, I want 'English' explanation :-)
Also, links on each method. Specifically, I'm interested in passing values to service for each method.

I want to understand how it works on low level.

Comment: What are your resources? What is the semantic of your requests? REST is about resources that are identified by URIs. The HTTP verb of a request made for such a resource describes the action you want to do on it.

Comment: Lets say my resource is a window. I'm a building company. Have an mobile app, which uses my API to check weather we have specific windows in warehouse, request them to a specific site. Another desktop or web app adds windows in a specific warehouse and remove them from it. (you can think about my question with another example, I just made this up)